# Is it possible to invoke an action in the controller after the view has loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to figure out how I can invoke a method in my controller when my view has loaded and rendered to the user. I've tried overriding the `OnResultExecuted` and `OnActionExecuted` but this does not seem to do the trick.

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    ConnectToDataSources();
    base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

The `ConnectToDataSources` method sets up a connection a wcf services on a remote server that uses SqlDependency to trigger live updates. Client-side I'm using SignalR to update the view every time there's a change. The services returns the last value from the database if there's no "live stream" of data. My problem is that it seems to be happening too fast so that my values are not being set properly in view.

If I try something silly as implementing a timer with a one second delay, the values are displayed. However, this is not a stable solution, so like I said, I'm trying to figure out how to wait for the view to be completely loaded before triggering the `ConnectToDataSources` method.

```
public void ConnectToDataSources()
{
    foreach (UnitDetailsModel unit in Model.UnitDetails)
    {
        var ods = new OperationDataSource();
        var ads = new ActivityStatusDataSource();

        ads.Start(unit.UnitId, ActivityReceived, AliveReceived);
        ods.Start(DataReceived, unit.UnitId);
        _dataSources.Add(ods);
        _activityStatusDataSources.Add(ads);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would do it client side (server has no knowledge about rendering things). When document is ready just start an AJAX request (ignoring result if you don't need it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server has no knowledge about rendering things then I'd suggest to do it from client, when document is ready, with an AJAX request:

```
$(document).ready(function {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Controller/Method', // Update with proper URL
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            // You may skip this if you don't expect any result
        }
    });
});
```

Now let's make it more *generic*, replace hard-coded URL with server side generated URL:

```
url: '@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")',
```

Of course you can even pass some data (`data` field in AJAX request). If you don't need any return value just declare your action method as `void` (optionally omit `success` function if you don't need any client-side check to be sure operation succeeded).

Comment: Can I call a void method, like ConnectoToDataSources? There's no need for me to return anything as I'm just setting up some connections.

Comment: @NicklasWinger yes, just declare it as void (well in reality it'll return EmptyResult).

Comment: Ah. Took me some time to figure it out, but I (of course) had to run the statement from a view and not a js-file (Due to the razor syntax) as well as adding [HttpGet] to my method. Now, on to the next problem; My model being null when `ConnectToDataSources` is invoked.

Comment: @NicklasWinger yes, it's a new request so it gets lost, you have to rebuild it (passing for example same parameters used by _main_ action method).